# "I/O operation on closed file" with StringIO in Django view test

Tags: python, django, wsgi, stringio

I inherited the following Django view code, used by another webservice to serve downloadable versions of output data:

```
def index(request):
    # ... (snip) ...
    data = base64.decodestring(request.POST['data'])
    filename = request.POST['filename']

    wrapper = FileWrapper(StringIO(data))

    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=guess_type(str(filename))[0])

    response['Content-Length'] = len(data)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=" + filename

    return response
```

The function itself — written against Django 1.0 — still works fine after upgrading to 1.5. Unfortunately, the test that covers this view is now failing:

```
    def testDownload(self):
        self.client.login(username='test', password='test')

        real = 'abc' * 100
        data = base64.encodestring(real)
        response = self.client.post("/api/v1/download/", {'data': data, 'filename': 'out.jpg'})

        self.assertEqual(real, response.content)
        self.assertEqual(response['Content-Disposition'], 'attachment; filename=out.jpg')
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fred/.secret_projects/final/gerbils/tests/amf.py", line 548, in testDownload
    self.assertEqual(real, response.content)
  File "/home/fred/.virtualenvs/cunning_plot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 282, in content
    self._consume_content()
  File "/home/carl/.virtualenvs/cunning_plot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 278, in _consume_content
    self.content = b''.join(self.make_bytes(e) for e in self._container)
  File "/home/carl/.virtualenvs/cunning_plot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 278, in <genexpr>
    self.content = b''.join(self.make_bytes(e) for e in self._container)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in next
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/StringIO.py", line 127, in read
    _complain_ifclosed(self.closed)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/StringIO.py", line 40, in _complain_ifclosed
    raise ValueError, "I/O operation on closed file"
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

So.. any ideas? I can't see anything in `testDownload()` or `index()` which would necessarily "close" the `StringIO` before it needs to be read. And if there were something, wouldn't it affect the non-test situation as well?

Very confused. Help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what `FileWrapper` is, but you should be able to do what you want without it. Try `file_content = StringIO(data)` and pass `file_content` to `HttpResponse` then rerun your test.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It's `django.core.servers.basehttp.FileWrapper`, FYI. Referred to in e.g. [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/), which I assume is why my predecessor used it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to see where `close` is being called is to just subclass `StringIO` and put a breakpoint in the close function.

```
class CustomStringIO(StringIO):
    def close(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        super(CustomStringIO, self).close()
```

The stack for this is

```
-> response = self.client.post("/test/", {'data': data, 'filename': 'out.jpg'})
  ...\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py(463)post()
-> response = super(Client, self).post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  ...\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py(297)post()
-> return self.request(**r)
  ...\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py(406)request()
-> response = self.handler(environ)
  ...\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py(119)__call__()
-> response.close()                    # will fire request_finished
  ...\venv\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py(233)close()
-> closable.close()
> \testapp\views.py(11)close()
-> super(CustomStringIO, self).close()
```

It looks like the test client is closing the response, which in turn calls close on `FileWrapper` which then calls close on `StringIO`.  This is all before you actually get to `response.content`.

Is there a reason why you need `FileWrapper`?  As `HttpResponse` takes in string content and `base64.decodestring` returns a binary string, it seems you could just pass `data` directly to `HttpResponse` instead of having to create a `StringIO` and `FileWrapper`.

Comment: Excellent idea subclassing `StringIO`, thank you (and posting the stack trace as well is icing on the already-delicious cake). I thought I'd already tried cutting out `StringIO` and `FileWrapper`, but I've just done so and it does indeed fix it. Marvellous: thanks!

Comment: Can't award your bounty for another 4 hours, but will do so as soon as I can.